# Eclipse PDE UI feature export with two fragments for same os, different arch

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-fragment

Hoping to have some Eclipse PDE guru's weigh in here in a problem I'm having trouble solving.

I am attempting export (via PDE UI) a feature that has two fragments included where both fragments target the same os (e.g., Linux) but have different architecture values (e.g., x86 and x86_64).  Each fragment has their own copy of several .so library files, which were built on the either Linux x86 or Linux x86 64 bit.  For example:

```
FragmentA (os=Linux,arch=x86)
   lib1.so
   lib2.so
   lib3.so

FragmentB (os=Linux,arch=x86_64)
   lib1.so
   lib2.so
   lib3.so
```

Exporting the hosting feature with using the corresponding delta pack to select either linux (gtk/x86) **OR** linux (gtk/x86_64), the export works as expected.  However, when I select **BOTH** platforms, the export fails with the following message:

```
Processing inclusion from feature com.sample.feature:
    Bundle com.sample.linux.x86_64_1.0.0.qualifier failed to resolve.:
    Unsatisfied native code filter:
        lib1.so; lib2.so; lib3.so; processor=x86_64; osname=linux.
```

Why can't I export both fragments together?  I also have a Win32 x86 fragment that I can export with the linux X86 feature but instead of having .so files, it has .dll files with the same file titles (e.g., lib1.dll, lib2.dll, lib3.dll).

Could having .so library files named the same in the two Linux-based fragments cause this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated as this is a critical block to our build process (both manually via the UI and headlessly).

Comment: I believe I might have just figured out why this was causing an error.  It appears to be related to the Bundle-NativeCode property in the fragment MANIFEST.MF file.  I copied this property from the existing fragment MANIFEST.MF file (the Linux x86 version) and pasted it into the new fragment MANIFEST.MF file (the Linux x86_64), adjusting for the processor / architecture value.  When I removed this from the newer Linux x86_64 fragment MANIFEST.MF file, the dual fragment export worked.  However, I'm not sure why.  Also, having files named the same in both fragments was not an issue.  Thoughts?

Comment: but exporting the x86_64 linux fragment and the windows fragment at the same time worked?

Comment: Correct, the linux x86_64 and win32 x86 exported just fine.  I truly believe this was tied to the attempted use of the Bundle-NativeCode entry that I was inserting manually (modeled after another fragment's MANIFEST.MF file).  I was also looking at [link]http://delaltctrl.blogspot.com/2010/02/perils-of-multi-platform-eclipse.html and [link]https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285229 for some assistance to my issue.